# How to consume a library with web services in it without having to define the endpoints in the consuming application's config file (e.g. app.config)?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, dll

I'm trying to develop a C# library that will be consumed in multiple C# based applications (e.g. WPF and ASP.NET projects), using the .NET framework.
My library depends on a specific web service (SOAP) which isn't necessarily in the consuming applications that will be using my library.

Is it any way possible for those applications to use my library without having to define the endpoints of the web services in my referenced library in its config file?

If not, how do "enterprise" type libraries solve this problem?...is this just a limitation of libraries?

Note, the error encountered when one doesn't define the matching endpoints in the consuming application is: "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'Web Service Contract Name' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuaration file was found for your application or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."

Comment: Unfortunately I do not fully understand what are you talking about. Can not the end-point be defined in any other place? Why do you think it must be defined in 'app.config'? You can have the end-point hard-coded, or in library specific configuration file. When I correctly remember, one of plug-in in Gendarme *(C# lint-type application)* also uses a SOAP service, but there is no global configuration in 'app.config' to define this service/end-point.

Comment: When you have a library with a web service in it, if you don't also copy the same end points of the web service from the app.config of the library to the app.config of the executing (consuming) application of the library, then you get the following error:

"Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'Web Service Contract Name' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuaration file was found for your application or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."

Comment: @Julo Re-reading your comment, I'll add that I wasn't aware that web service endpoints could be defined in other places than the app.config (I just am accustomed to that being the default place they're added when you add a web service to a .NET / C# project.) 

My point is it appears an error occurs when the endpoint is not defined in both the library and the executing (consuming) application that references that library. My question is is there a way where I don't have to define the endpoint in the executing (consuming) application for the web service that's only in the referenced library?

Comment: Is this a limitation/'feature' of WPF and/or ASP.NET? This is unfortunately not my field of expertise. I know for sure, that there is no such a request/limitation for Windows desktop applications (GUI/console) and also it should be no problem for Linux/mono since Gendarme is a Linux/mono application. The definition in another place might be a little 'out of standard way', but when the consuming application should not know how the underlying layer works, it may be the only way. But I do not know, whether there is a system limitation. In this case there might be another way how to bypass this.

Comment: From my research it appears that this is a limitation of some sort in C# / .NET based Windows applications. (E.g. it occurs in WPF, ASP.NET, WinForms, etc.)